# getResponseAsStream - What does the InputStream point to?

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am curious as to how [getResponseAsStream](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html#getResponseBodyAsStream()) for HttpClient is actually working.

According to this [article](https://layer4.fr/blog/2011/09/08/httpclient-best-pratices/), you should use `getResponseAsStream` instead of loading the entire response into memory.

My question is how is this working, to where does the InputStream point to?

Take an example where a particular REST service request returns a generated JSON **where would the server store that, so it can be streamed to the client**? The main memory is the only option.

If that is the case you are not solving the problem of memory depletion. **How is this really working?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following, extremely simplified scenario:

The server generates loads of data, e.g. by reading a large files. It writes the data via an OutputStream into a send buffer. The networking stack reads data from the send buffer and sends packages of data to the client. Here the incoming data is put into a receive buffer.

Eventually the receive buffer is full, and the client stops accepting data packages from the server. This causes the send buffer to fill up. At this point the server is paused, since it can no longer put data into the send buffer.

The client uses `getResponseAsStream` to get a InputStream implementation that reads data from the receive buffer. As soon as the client reads data through the InputStream the receive buffer empties, the networking stack on the client side again accepts data packages, which causes the send buffer on the sever side to drain. Now the server can write data into the buffer again.

This way the client can read any amount of data, and the system never needs more space than the send and receive buffer.

Of course, this is extremely simplified. There are more layers, and more buffers involved. But I hope this explains the basic principle.

Comment: so the InputStream actually points to that buffer on the server? Assuming we are over-simplifying things.

Comment: @ng.newbie yes, the InputStream-Implementation will have a reference to a receive buffe, or something equivalent.

Comment: @ng.newbie remember that InputStream is just an Interface, describing a functionality that lets you read bytes sequentially. Where the bytes come from is hidden in the implementation.

Comment: So the whole point of using an InputStream is so that I can process more data with a reasonably small buffer, right? Otherwise a large buffer would have be allocated to hold the entire input.

Comment: @ng.newbie yes and no. The point of using the InputStream returned by getResponseAsStream is to allow you to process the data without reading everything into memory. The point of using an InputStream is that you don't can sequentially read data without having to know where it comes from.

Comment: Yeah but take the case where I am reading the InputStream from start to end, in that case I am reading the entire stream into memory is it not?

Comment: @ng.newbie It depends on what you do with every byte you read. If you store it in an array or something, then yes, every byte ends up being stored in memory. If you print it to the console, or write it to a file, or write it to some othe output stream, then no, everything isn't stored into memory. Just like when you watch a stream of video frames on the television: once a frame has been shown, it's discarded and replaced by the next one. The whole video doesn't need to be stored in memory.